# Bug in CSS3 rotateY transition on Safari?

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions

I am showing a modal popup using CSS3 transitions (largely borrowed from [Effeckt.css](http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/)). It works well in all modern browsers except Safari. In Safari, the movement is OK, but the background-color snaps in unevenly.

This is the code, the problem is visible in Safari on OSX: http://jsfiddle.net/eJsZx/4/

A screenshot of the problem before it resolves itself. You can see that half the div is correctly colored white, half is still transparent.

[image]

This is the relevant part of the CSS (`.effeckt-show` and `.md-effect-8` are applied when the button is clicked, to show the modal):

```
.effeckt-modal {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: white;
}
.md-effect-8 {
  -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
  -ms-perspective: 1300px;
  -o-perspective: 1300px;
  perspective: 1300px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.md-effect-8 .effeckt-modal {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-70deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-70deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-70deg);
  transform: rotateY(-70deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  opacity: 0;
}
.effeckt-show.md-effect-8 .effeckt-modal {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621544/webkit-transform-breaks-z-index-on-safari contains some clues on why this is happening.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's a bug, yes, Safari is rendering intersection where it shouldn't.

For some time [I thought Safari is doing it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203550/how-to-recreate-perspective-origin-effect-by-transforming-child-elements/17409218#17409218) by always rendering intersection of elements, but as far as I understand [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-transforms-1-20131126/#3d-transform-rendering), only elements in the same [3d rendering context](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-transforms-1-20131126/#3d-rendering-context) should intersect, and that would be children of elements with a `transform-style` of `preserve-3d`.

So far the only workaround I found (only tested on Windows yet where Safari shows the same behaviour) is to translate the underlying elements away on the z-axis. Without perspective being applied it won't actually translate, but Safari/Webkit seems to think it does (which probably is because it mistakenly treats the element as if it were in the same 3d rendering context as the actually transformed dialog) and so the elements do no longer intersect.

```
.effeckt-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    transition: 500ms;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1000px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eJsZx/5/

Comment: For my solution http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/cdcnyfr6/, I've to make a small change `-webkit-transform: translateZ(1000px);` and it worked like a charm. My +1. Thanks #ndm

Comment: Saved my butt! Thank you :) FWIW, `-1000px` isn't necessary if you don't have crazy Z translations already, you can get away with `-1px`.

Comment: This bug still exists in 2019! Is there a solution that doesn't involve Z translations? Because I _am_ using perspective, a Z translation would be visible.

Comment: @Thomas I've never found another solution, but I also didn't really look into it much anymore. Can't test it right now as Safari for Windows is dead, and I have no MacOS VM set up currently, sorry...

Comment: I got it to work by putting a `z-index: 0` on the parent element, but my situation is slightly different so I'll leave this as a comment, rather than posting an answer.

Comment: My solution was to put my element in a wrapper to which I applied `-webkit-transform: translateZ(1000px);` so my whole animation is above the rest instead of tricking the navigator into thinking the parent is under using a negative value, I found that easier.

Comment: z-axis means the axis that one can not see and goes inside. is this the thing? so are we moving them further away on that axis?

Comment: In my opinion, `translateZ` is similar to `z-index` but in 3d-space.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it worked to put `transform: translateZ(0);` on the parent container. The object itself is an image.

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue when trying to find a solution to a problem I was experiencing in Safari (Mac and iOS), where a y-rotated svg only displayed its right half for no apparent reason.

In my case, the svg was a child of a fixed-position div, and I found that both `position: fixed` and `position: absolute` on the parent caused half the svg to disappear.

Neither changing z indexes, perspective, nor translate-z seemed to solve the issue.  But randomly, adding a new div around my svg and setting its background-color solved the problem.  I hope this helps the next person :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, adding `z-index: 0` to the parent element fixed it as per Thomas's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions above worked for me. In the end, this is a bug with `rotate` on Safari that Chrome previously had but fixed. [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820613/7266916) was what solved it for me - using `scale()` rather than `rotate()`.

Answer (score 0):

On the "back" side element that is translated 180 deg in Y, I added a 1px Z translation and it fixed my Safari bug.

```css
transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
```

If the front & back elements are in the same z-index in Safari, this bug seems to be present.

There is a CodePen here where you can remove then `translateZ(1px)` and watch the bug show up.   In my example case, the back side of the element has in "input" and "button" and the left half of both the input and button don't work due to the Safari bug.

See working code example here:

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/mullojo-the-bashful/pen/dywQdrq)