# Text blurry after super simple CSS3 Transform animation

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

As simple as it is, I can't get this animation to work properly.

What I am animating on hovering a div is:

- transform3d(0, Xem, 0)
- border
- height

so, nothing special. But when I open this in Chrome, I'm getting a really poorly performing hover animation.

And the worst thing is that **the transform 3d makes my text blurry.** WHY? There is no zoom or any 3D effect.

Have a look in your browser: [Click](http://markmaurer.de/test/)

Am I missing something? This seems like a quite simple animation.

**div before hover**

[image: div before hover]

**div hovered (blurry text)**

[image]

**The CSS Code (SASS) is basically:**

```
.disciplines-wrapper > div {
color: white;
padding: 0;
width: 33%;
margin-right: .5%;
margin-top: 320px;
height: 12em;
height: 8.375em;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;


.wrap {
    height: 8.375em;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out, border 0.2s ease-out;
    border: 1px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;


    &:hover {
        transform: translate3d(0, -3.475em, 0);
        height: 11.875em;
        border: 1px solid $lightblue;
        background: $lightblue;

    }
}
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div class="disciplines-wrapper">

            <div class="col-1-3">

                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="disciplines-text-wrapper">
                            <h1>
                                Kreation
                            </h1>
                            <p>Effektive Werbung entsteht durch das optimale Zusammenspiel aller Kreativen. </p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icon-right-circled"></i>Weitere Informationen</a>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-1-3">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="disciplines-text-wrapper">
                            <h1>
                                Druck
                            </h1>
                            <p>Kernkompetenz von Prinovis ist der Druck. Schnell, hochwertig und flexibel.</p>

                        </div>
                        <a href="#"><i class="icon-right-circled"></i>Weitere Informationen</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1-3">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="disciplines-text-wrapper">
                        <h1>
                            Weiterverarbeitung
                        </h1>
                        <p>Nach dem Druck ist vor der Verarbeitung: Sammelheftung oder Klebebindung</p>

                    </div>
                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-right-circled"></i>Weitere Informationen</a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024061/webkit-blurry-text-with-css-scale-translate3d and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176557/text-blurry-after-3d-transform and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326220/blurry-text-on-transformrotate-in-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome

Comment: You might have resolved it already but, to me, The text seems pretty neat. I'm using Chrome 43.0.2357.132 if this can help you. http://i.imgur.com/woCYhND.png

Comment: @isherwood nothing of this seems to work, thats why i created a new post

Comment: @Bladepianist thank you! what operating system are you using?

Comment: Ah yes, I might have have said it earlier. I'm on a Win' XP computer. And no blurry text on my phone either, Note 3 with last version of Chrome too nor Android Lollipop integrated browser. Firefox 35.0.1 is all good too.

Comment: @user3561012 Can you try add text-shadow on h1 element? text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #101010;  The text stay bluried, but much readable.

Comment: This worked for me.

`zoom: 1.005;`
Hope this helps you too.

This will make your content a little bit big but the blur problem will be solved. Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: None of the css hacks work, it requires a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59363865/1