# CSS transform causing div to overlap in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, browser-bugs

Why does `transform:rotateY();` cause a div to overlap in Safari only? Here are some screen shots to better explain...

> What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

> What it shouldn't look like (only occurs in Safari):

[image]

This is very strange behavior, I have since removed the `transform:rotateY();` from the entire code but it brings up valid confusion about why this is happening.

Here is a code snippet of the original program:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var percentHeight = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 100);
  var percentWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 100);
  initializeMessages();
  var hourHand = document.getElementById('watchHourHand');
  var minuteHand = document.getElementById('watchMinuteHand');
  var secondHand = document.getElementById('watchSecondHand');
  var markers = document.getElementById('markers');
  for (var i = 0; i != 12; i++) {
    var marker = document.createElement('div');
    marker.className = 'marker';
    markers.appendChild(marker);
    markers.appendChild(marker);
  }
  window.setInterval(function() {
    //minute degrees = 6
    //second degrees = 6
    //hour degrees = 30
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    if (hours > 12) {
      hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
      hours = 12;
    }
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var secondDegrees = seconds * 6;
    var minuteDegrees = minutes * 6 + seconds / 60;
    var hourDegrees = hours * 30 + minutes / 60;
    if (hourDegrees == 0) {
      //hourHand.className = 'noTransition';
      hourDegrees = 360;
    }
    hourHand.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + hourDegrees + 'deg)';
    hourHand.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + hourDegrees + 'deg)';
    hourHand.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + hourDegrees + 'deg)';
    hourHand.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + hourDegrees + 'deg)';
    hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + hourDegrees + 'deg)';
    if (hourDegrees == 360) {
      hourHand.style.oTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      hourHand.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      hourHand.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      hourHand.style.msTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      hourHand.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      hourHand.className = 'noTransition';
    }
    if (minuteDegrees == 0) {
      //minuteHand.className = 'noTransition';
      minuteDegrees = 360;
    }
    minuteHand.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + minuteDegrees + 'deg)';
    minuteHand.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + minuteDegrees + 'deg)';
    minuteHand.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + minuteDegrees + 'deg)';
    minuteHand.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + minuteDegrees + 'deg)';
    minuteHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + minuteDegrees + 'deg)';
    if (minuteDegrees == 360) {
      minuteHand.style.oTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      minuteHand.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      minuteHand.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      minuteHand.style.msTransform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      minuteHand.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
      minuteHand.className = 'noTransition';
    }
    if (secondDegrees == 0) {
      //secondHand.className = 'noTransition';
      secondDegrees = 360;
    }
    secondHand.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + secondDegrees + 'deg)';
    secondHand.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + secondDegrees + 'deg)';
    secondHand.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + secondDegrees + 'deg)';
    secondHand.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + secondDegrees + 'deg)';
    secondHand.style.transform = 'rotate(' + secondDegrees + 'deg)';
    if (secondDegrees == 360) {
      secondHand.style.oTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';
      secondHand.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';
      secondHand.style.msTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';
      secondHand.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';
      secondHand.style.transform = 'rotate(360deg)';
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        secondHand.className = 'noTransition';
      }, 1000)
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      secondHand.className = '';
      minuteHand.style.className = '';
      hourHand.style.className = '';
    }, 500);
  }, 1000);

  function initializeMessages() {
    var messages = ['Modern 12 hour time invented <span class="hyphen">-</span> 2000 BC (Egyptians)', 'Sundial <span class="hyphen">-</span> 1500 BC (Egyptians)', 'Candle clock <span class="hyphen">-</span> 520 AD (Chinese)', 'Salisbury cathedral clock <span class="hyphen">-</span> 1386 AD Europe', 'Pendulum clock <span class="hyphen">-</span> 1580 AD France', 'Pocket watch <span class="hyphen">-</span> 1675 AD England', 'Wristwatch <span class="hyphen">-</span> 1571 AD England', 'Electric clock <span class="hyphen">-</span> 1814 AD London England'];
    var fontSizes = [18, 28, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52];
    var messageSource = document.getElementById('messages');
    for (var i = 0; i != messages.length; i++) {
      var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
      messageDiv.className = 'message';
      messageDiv.style.fontSize = fontSizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontSizes.length)] + 'px';
      messageDiv.innerHTML = messages[i];
      messageSource.appendChild(messageDiv);
    }
  }
  window.setInterval(function() {
    var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
    var randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    randomMessage.style.display = 'block';
    randomMessage.style.opacity = '1';

    randomMessagePercentHeight = randomMessage.clientHeight / percentHeight;
    randomMessagePercentWidth = randomMessage.clientWidth / percentWidth;

    randomMessage.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - randomMessagePercentWidth)) + 'vw';
    randomMessage.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - randomMessagePercentHeight)) + 'vh';
  }, 2000);
  var messages = document.getElementsByClassName('message');
  window.setInterval(function() {
    var randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    randomMessage.style.opacity = '0';
  }, messages.length * 500);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    percentHeight = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 100);
    percentWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 100);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@-o-keyframes pageBackground {
  0% {
    background-color: #091321;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #3C1217;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #16310D;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #3A1831;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes pageBackground {
  0% {
    background-color: #091321;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #3C1217;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #16310D;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #3A1831;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pageBackground {
  0% {
    background-color: #091321;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #3C1217;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #16310D;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #3A1831;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes pageBackground {
  0% {
    background-color: #091321;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #3C1217;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #16310D;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #3A1831;
  }
}
@keyframes pageBackground {
  0% {
    background-color: #091321;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #3C1217;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #16310D;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #3A1831;
  }
}
#projectContainer {
  background-color: #091321;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -o-animation: pageBackground 20s infinite;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation: pageBackground 20s infinite;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation: pageBackground 20s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation: pageBackground 20s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: pageBackground 20s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#verticalAlign {
  -o-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
#watchBeltContainer {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: -12.5vh;
}
#watchBelt {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 3px #444;
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
}
#glass {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aaa;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 1000000000000000;
  /*left:15%;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  -o-filter: blur(20px);
  -moz-filter: blur(20px);
  -ms-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
}
#watchContainer {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2vh;
  /*background-color:#AB9883;*/
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  overflow: visible;
}
#watchStructure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}
#watchFace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background: -ms-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #eee);
    background: linear-gradient(-35deg, #444, #999);
    position:relative;*/
  /*background-color:#0E1021;*/
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #333;
}
#watchHourHand {
  height: 30%;
  width: 3%;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48.5%;
  top: 20%;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#watchMinuteHand {
  width: 3%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48.5%;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#watchSecondHand {
  width: 1%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 49%;
  -o-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
#watchHandButton {
  width: 4%;
  height: 4%;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 48%;
  z-index: 100000;
}
#markers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.marker {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #82715E;
}
/*marker positioning*/

.marker {
  width: 3%;
  height: 8%;
}
.marker:nth-child(1) {
  left: 48.5%;
}
.marker:nth-child(2) {
  left: 72%;
  top: 6.5%;
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(3) {
  left: 88.5%;
  top: 23%;
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(4) {
  left: 92%;
  top: 48.5%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 3%;
}
.marker:nth-child(5) {
  top: 69%;
  left: 88.5%;
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(6) {
  top: 85.5%;
  left: 72%;
  -o-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(7) {
  top: 92%;
  left: 48.5%;
}
.marker:nth-child(8) {
  top: 85.5%;
  left: 26%;
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(9) {
  top: 69%;
  left: 8.5%;
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(10) {
  top: 48.5%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 3%;
}
.marker:nth-child(11) {
  top: 23%;
  left: 8.5%;
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.marker:nth-child(12) {
  top: 6%;
  left: 26%;
  -o-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
/*end marker positioning*/

.message {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  /*color:#555;*/
  color: #444;
  /*-webkit-text-stroke: 1px #555;*/
  /*text-shadow:
      -.5px -.5px 0 #333,  
      .5px -.5px 0 #333,
      -.5px .5px 0 #333,
       .5px .5px 0 #333;*/
  /*text-shadow:-2px -2px 2px #555;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  -o-transition: all 10s ease, opacity 2s ease, display 0s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 10s ease, opacity 2s ease, display 0s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 10s ease, opacity 2s ease, display 0s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 10s ease, opacity 2s ease, display 0s ease;
  transition: all 10s ease, opacity 2s ease, display 0s ease;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  padding: 2%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
* {
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.noTransition {
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
  -o-animation-direction: reverse;
  -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  -ms-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<div id="projectContainer">
  <div id="messages"></div>
  <div id="verticalAlign">
    <div id="watchContainer">
      <div id="watchStructure">
        <div id="watchFace">
          <div id="watchBeltContainer">
            <div id="watchBelt"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="glass"></div>
          <div id="markers"></div>
          <div id="watchHourHand"></div>
          <div id="watchMinuteHand"></div>
          <div id="watchSecondHand"></div>
          <div id="watchHandButton"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Safari users, look closely at the #watchBelt styles (look at the top of the CSS code block in the snippet for code that is also relevant to #watchBelt). Here is the #watchBelt code:

```
#watchBelt {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 100%;
      background: #555;
      border-radius: 50px;
      box-shadow: 0px -10px 3px #444;
      transform: rotateY(20deg);
    }
```

I have not tested this in IE or Edge and I would be appreciative of anyone who could tell me what happens in IE and/or Edge. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this bug?

Answer (score 1):

In Safari the z-value seems to be involved in determining which object gets rendered infront. Making sure the object you want rendered in foreground has a higher z-value should solve the problem:

```
.yourForegroundClass {
   /* Your Style */
   transform: translateZ(999999px);
}
```

This is obviously not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#watchBelt {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      height: 100%;
      background: #555;
      border-radius: 50px;
      box-shadow: 0px -10px 3px #444;
      transform: rotateY(20deg);
position :relative;
z-index:-1;/*decrease it until it moves to back*/
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not working :) Thank you for your answer though and welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: The important bit here is "position:relative;"

Comment: Maybe this helps someone: add "perspective: 1000px" to a wraper layer, found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621544/webkit-transform-breaks-z-index-on-safari