# transform:scale() breaking my z-index order

Tags: html, css, transform, z-index

I did setup an HTML page where I use z-index to set the elements "visual" order.
It works as expected; but breaks when I use *transform: scale()*.

```
#blocks-both{
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

I make a simplified example here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNYrar

I read a lot of messages regarding this particular problem, but I can't find a solution to make my design work.
I guess I don't understand something regarding this.

Could someone help ?

Thanks !

Comment: so confused! why you used `transform: scale` on your container?

Comment: This is a simplified example, but i need to use *transform:scale* on this page (to scale content and avoid scrollbars)

Comment: who told you that scaling elements prevents scrollbars? If you don't want scrollbars you can use percentage or viewport based layout (`%` or `vh`/`vw` units) or adding `overflow:hidden` to body

Comment: Hi Aziz, thanks for your reply.  I know that; but for my particular design I NEED to use transform-scale at that moment.  My question is not how to avoid scrollbars, but how to have my z-indexes working with *transform:scale()* enabled...  Thanks !

Comment: Because a transform affect the block stacking order...this is known behavior as I recall. You may have to set the z-index manually...but @Aziz is right...you're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: What do you mean about setting the z-index manually ? BTW, I need an horizontal scale, not only avoid scrollbars.  That's why i'm using *scale*.

Comment: Any reason why you're scaling **#blocks-both** and not **#block-main** and **#block-sidebar** individually?

Comment: you know you could space out elements by applying margin or padding, instead of scale...

Comment: @ Cosmin Ababei : no, no reason for that...

Comment: Cosmin Ababei : it works scaling both elements instead of #blocks-both !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue:

- [css z-index lost after webkit transform translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d)
- [webkit-transform breaks z-index on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621544/webkit-transform-breaks-z-index-on-safari)
- [webkit-transform overwrites z-index ordering in Chrome 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953497/webkit-transform-overwrites-z-index-ordering-in-chrome-13)

You can read more about it [here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) as it offers in depth explanation.

> In addition to opacity, several newer CSS properties also create stacking contexts. These include: transforms, filters, css-regions, paged media, and possibly others. As a general rule, it seems that if a CSS property requires rendering in an offscreen context, it must create a new stacking context.

You could avoid this issue by moving the transform properties from **#blocks-both** to **#block-main** and **#block-sidebar** like this:

```css
#block-main, #block-sidebar {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

#block-main {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

#block-sidebar {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

I've also edited your [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzKBRX).