# Safari display flex issue

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have a video as a background which has an overlay and then some text with buttons. It displays correctly on all browsers except Safari.

Could someone please help me make it compatible?

I'm wondering if there's a solution that I can't see before I take a different approach in doing this. Also, if there is an easier approach to do what I'm trying to do, please tell me!

By the way, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7

```css
body .home-page .vid-header {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

body .home-page .vid-header .video-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .home-page .vid-header .video-wrap video {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

body .home-page .vid-header .header-overlay {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #1A1F41;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.91;
}

body .home-page .vid-header .header-content {
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-page">
  <div class="vid-header">
    <div class="video-wrap">
      <video autoplay="true" loop="true" height="1080px" width="1920px" muted>
        <source src="media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">Text</h1>
            <h4 class="text-center">Text</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buttons h-button-second">Button</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg buttons h-button-second">Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: The text and buttons disappear, but the video and overlay are intact. I'm testing my site on my phone's safari so I guess it's the latest version.

Comment: I also did a compability test on Safari 8, which returns: This value is not supported by this browser: flex

Comment: I think the `-webkit-` prefix still may be required for some CSS definitions on IOS Safari 8. For example, see [CanIUse/Flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and [CanIUse/Transform](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Comment: -webkit prefix does not change anything, just tried it

Comment: -webkit- prefix is also different for flex I think its is `-webkit-box` you could also try pasting your code in autoprefixer https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: Could be a [stacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) issue? See [webkit-transform breaks z-index on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621544/webkit-transform-breaks-z-index-on-safari). I could reproduce the problem in Safari 11 and had some success by setting `position:relative;z-index:2;` on `.header-content`.

Comment: position: relative fixed it. Thank you so much! :)