# How can I smoothen rotateY transform in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, gsap

I first tried using CSS, but when I was informed that it looks buggy on Safari, I tried with Greensock's Javascript library to see if it fixes it. It still has the same issues, still only on Safari. After a bit of research I saw it [discussed on StackOverflow as a Safari bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146511/bug-in-css3-rotatey-transition-on-safari).

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/ricardoh/pen/jbQvBy)

```
jQuery(function($){
var iconsHoverIn = function() {
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.iconBG'), 0.5, {
        rotationY: 180, 
        opacity: 0
        }
    );
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.hoverImage'), 0.5, {
        rotationY: '-180', 
        opacity: 1
        }
    );
}
var iconsHoverOut = function() {
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.iconBG'), 0.5, {
        rotationY: 0, 
        opacity: 1
        }
    );
    TweenMax.to($(this).find('.hoverImage'), 0.5, {
        rotationY: 0, 
        opacity: 0
        }
    );
}

$('.iconBlock').hover(iconsHoverIn, iconsHoverOut);

});
```

The bug is: while doing the transition, half of the element seems to transition differently than the other half. It shows a line in the middle, like if the element was made of paper and was bending in half.

Is there any way around it? I presented a few animations to the client, but this animation (rotateY) was the unanimous selection.

Note: I am somewhat new to Javascript and Greensock. You may notice better ways to do what I did. I wouldn't mind suggestions on improving it, but what I am really after is a solution to the bug/glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the solution you posted in your question itself suggests, adding a `translateZ` (which in GSAP terms just means `z`) to either `.iconBG` element or `.hoverImage` element should solve your problem.

Here is the **[forked codepen](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/WQYPwd?editors=001)** of your demo and the code is as belows:

**JavaScript:**

```
var iconBlocks = $('.iconBlock');
var iconBGs = iconBlocks.find('.iconBG');
var hoverImages = iconBlocks.find('.hoverImage');
var animDuration = 0.4;
var animEase = Power2.easeOut;
var numIcons = iconBlocks.length;
var timelines = [];
var timeline = null;
for (var i = 0; i < numIcons; i += 1) {
  timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
  timeline.fromTo(iconBGs[i], animDuration, { z: 0, rotationY: 0, autoAlpha: 1 }, { rotationY: 180, autoAlpha: 0, ease: animEase }, 0);
  timeline.fromTo(hoverImages[i], animDuration, { z: 100, rotationY: 180, autoAlpha: 0 }, { rotationY: 0, autoAlpha: 1, ease: animEase }, 0);
  timelines[i] = timeline;
}
iconBlocks.hover(function() { timelines[$(this).index()].play(); }, function() { timelines[$(this).index()].reverse(); });
```

And yes, I have changed things a bit. Personal preference totally, no right or wrong ways here. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You are awesome! This answer solved the issue and I'm still learning about a better implementation. Unfortunately when I applied it to the actual project it didn't fix the problem there, but this answer did solve the problem presented in the Codepen. Thank you