# Sidenav flicker on mobile

Tags: css

On my portfolio website (which I'm currently in the process of building), my side navigation which contains a custom animation, is flickering on mobile - Safari and Chrome on iPhone. This is not happening on desktop at all.

i've tried using `backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` as well as `translate3d:` on the animation containers but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Link:  [revill.io](https://revill.io)

Comment: HEY!  HEADS UP!  Testing this on my iPad (2018) has introduced a problem on my display that persists outside of the browser and even after a power-down. Where your mobile menu appeared, my screen is constantly flickering!!!  =(

Comment: While I nurse my iPad, and look for the warranty... Simon: Do you think the bug is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146511/bug-in-css3-rotatey-transition-on-safari)?

Comment: Wow, really? That’s odd... I hope your iPad sorts itself out. Sorry about that. I will check out the other post.

Comment: The display flicker is starting to calm down now, although still apparent with dark backgrounds. Really strange.

Comment: I can only imagine this is a coincidence and/or software glitch that has persisted with iOS

Comment: Yes it could be a coincidence, as iPad's have known flickering issues. I would guess that some underlying iPad issue got triggered by intense CSS 3d processing. In any case, the flicker had a sheared diagonal shape resembling the rendering glitch of the rotating cube.

Comment: That was exactly what I saw on my phone

Comment: Ok, maybe iPhone displays can handle it better than iPad's.

Comment: Just an FYI for others: checking a few hours later, the iPad screen issue has cleared up.