# How do I best fix Safari perspective (TranslateZ) stacking context without affecting other browsers?

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm attempting to implement Parallax Scrolling using CSS Perspective, but Safari applies negative transforms differently from Chrome and Firefox.

[Here is an image showing the issue. Left is Safari, right is Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnsP4.png)

The intended behavior is that of Firefox. Chrome works exactly as Firefox does.

[Here is the jsfiddle showing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/vqkLw17a/17/)

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallax_root">
    <div class="prlx back_cat">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/800/cats/">
    </div>
    <div class="prlx front_food">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/200/food/">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
.parallax_root {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1px;
  perspective: 1px;
}

.prlx {
  position: absolute;
}

.back_cat {
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}

.front_food {
  transform: translateZ(-2px);
}
```

Is there any way of achieving the correct parallax effect on Safari without breaking the functionality on other browsers, especially when taking into account multiple parallax layers?

Comment: Yeah, Safari always got it weird: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146511/bug-in-css3-rotatey-transition-on-safari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I did see both of those but it doesn't look like either refers to perspective specifically (over Z-index) since I would like to have CSS-only scrolling.

Comment: I think the core of the issue is the same in all three cases: Safari stacks incorrectly 3D rendering contexts.

Comment: So what would be the correct solution in this case then, reverse the perspective values for webkit?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know, otherwise I would have answered already ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway @Kaiido ! I rephrased my question a bit so maybe someone who has dealt with the issue before could give some further insight.

Comment: Yes your question looks better now. I hope someone will have a solution for you, and if you do find one on your own, remember that you are welcome to self-answer your own question.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?